# Deleting record from table in React moves the input value of column to the adjacent row input

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, rerender

There is the table which holds records, that is the oust-standing amount to be paid. Amount is paid by entering the transaction ID in the input field of table and clicking the pay button. When clicked on the pay button the record gets deleted but the transaction id moves to the adjacent row( input type in row ). How to avoid this problem ?

**The code:-**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Row, Form, Button, Table, Spinner, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

const dummyData = [
    {
        createdDate: '2020-11-27T18:25:56.827',
        modifiedDate: '2020-12-20T15:20:37.739',
        createdBy: 1,
        modifiedBy: 1,
        id: 175,
        name: 'Delicious Point',
        description: 'Kitchen 4',
        email: 'saqqasc@gmail.com',
        address: 'djshdjsdsdssdassssh',
        locality: 'Andheri',
        type: 'Home',
        recommended: true,
        available: true,
        logo: '0073217b-e4eb-4400-9cef-6f03dbce80f0.jpeg',
        status: 'ACTIVE',
        deliveryPrice: 20.0,
        ownerName: 'Kitchen 4',
        alternatePhone: '4256879097',
        fssaiLicenceApplied: true,
        fssaiLicence: null,
        gstNumber: '',
        gstPercent: 0.0,
        pendingAmount: 200.0,
        totalAmount: 200.0,
        transactionAmount: 0,
        settlementDate: '2020-12-20',
    },
    {
        createdDate: '2020-11-03T12:35:18.751',
        modifiedDate: '2020-12-20T14:25:21.601',
        createdBy: 1,
        modifiedBy: 1,
        id: 163,
        name: 'Shop321',
        description: 'description',
        email: 'rehan123@gmail.com',
        address: 'description',
        locality: 'near Gausiya hotel',
        type: 'Restaurant',
        recommended: true,
        available: true,
        logo: null,
        status: 'ACTIVE',
        deliveryPrice: 23.0,
        ownerName: 'Shop321',
        fssaiLicenceApplied: true,
        fssaiLicence: null,
        gstNumber: '0',
        gstPercent: 5.0,
        pendingAmount: 460.0,
        totalAmount: 460.0,
        transactionAmount: 0,
        settlementDate: '2020-12-20',
    },
    {
        createdDate: '2020-11-03T12:35:18.751',
        modifiedDate: '2020-12-20T14:25:21.601',
        createdBy: 1,
        modifiedBy: 1,
        id: 168,
        name: 'Shop3212',
        description: 'description',
        email: 'rehan1232@gmail.com',
        address: 'description',
        locality: 'near Gausiya hotelz',
        type: 'Restaurant',
        recommended: true,
        available: true,
        logo: null,
        status: 'ACTIVE',
        deliveryPrice: 23.0,
        ownerName: 'Shop321',
        fssaiLicenceApplied: true,
        fssaiLicence: null,
        gstNumber: '0',
        gstPercent: 5.0,
        pendingAmount: 460.0,
        totalAmount: 460.0,
        transactionAmount: 0,
        settlementDate: '2020-12-20',
    },
    {
        createdDate: '2020-11-03T12:35:18.751',
        modifiedDate: '2020-12-20T14:25:21.601',
        createdBy: 1,
        modifiedBy: 1,
        id: 169,
        name: 'Shop32134',
        description: 'description',
        email: 'reh14@gmail.com',
        address: 'description',
        type: 'Restaurant',
        recommended: true,
        available: true,
        logo: null,
        status: 'ACTIVE',
        deliveryPrice: 23.0,
        ownerName: 'Shop321',
        fssaiLicenceApplied: true,
        fssaiLicence: null,
        gstNumber: '0',
        gstPercent: 5.0,
        pendingAmount: 460.0,
        totalAmount: 460.0,
        transactionAmount: 0,
        settlementDate: '2020-12-20',
    },
];
export default function Settelments(props) {
   const [date, setData] = useState([]);
   useEffect(() => {
        setalert1(true);
        setDdata(dummyData);
   ),[]}
   const sendData = (e) => {
        const sid = e.target.id;
        setShopid(sid);
        setDeleteId(parseInt(e.target.id));
        const dat = ddate
            .filter((f) => f.id !== parseInt(e.target.id))
            .map((m) => {
                return m;
            });
        setDdata(dat);
        setValues({
            val: [],
        });
        setSdata({
            ...sdata,
            date: time,
        });
    };

    const handleChange = (e, index) => {
        setValues(e.target.value);
     };

   return(
            <Table responsive>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th className="text-center">Sr.no</th>
                    <th className="text-center">Shop Name</th>
                    <th
                        className="text-center"
                        style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'white' }}
                    >
                        Pending Amount
                    </th>
                    <th className="text-center">Type</th>
                    <th className="text-center">Transaction Id</th>

                    <th className="text-center">Settlement</th>

                    <th className="text-center">{''}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {noofelement == 0 ? (
                    <tr className="text-center">
                        <td className="align-middle">
                            <div className="text-danger">No Data Found</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ) : null}
                {ddate.map((m, index) => (
                    <tr id={m.id} className="text-center">
                        <td scope="row">{index + 1}</td>
                        <td>{m.name}</td>

                        <td className="text-danger">
                            <b>{m.totalAmount}</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>{m.type}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div className="transaction-settelment">
                                <Form.Group controlId={m.id}>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="Transaction ID"
                                        name={`tid${m.id}`}
                                        size="sm"
                                        onChange={(e, index) => {
                                            handleChange(e, index);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <Button size="sm" id={m.id} onClick={(e) => sendData(e)}>
                                Pay!
                            </Button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </Table>
   )
}
```

Comment: It is to do with the way react finds the most efficient way to update the DOM. Basically it's reusing the row. The way to fix it is to make the input controlled and put the value into state, then reset the state when you're finished with it. I would make each row a separate component to better separate this logic. I'm on a phone so can't write that much code

Comment: If you passing a key to `ddate.map((m, index) => (<tr key={m.id} id={m.id} className="text-center">...` Does it solve the issue ?

Comment: @saif, could you please provide the logic? I am also in the same boat. Appreciate your help.